# Заполнение коллекций( джава 9 )

Tags: java, коллекции

```
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 3, 54, 54,5, 4,43);
    System.out.println(list);

    // Строка ниже не компилируется 
    //ArrayList<Integer> list1 = List.of(1, 3, 54, 54,5, 4,43);

    Set<Integer> set = Set.of(1, 3, 54,5, 4,43);
    System.out.println(set);

    Map<String, String> map = Map.ofEntries(Map.entry("11", "111"), Map.entry("htfg", "222"));
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

}

Насколько я знаю List, Set и Map - это интерфейсы , сами по себе не представляющие реализации, отсюда вопрос какой будет реализация например листа (список(если да , то какой)  массив ?????)

Comment: А он и не должен компилится - это не совместимо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The collections created using the factory methods are not commonly
>   used implementations.
>
> For example, the List is not an ArrayList and the Map is not a
>   HashMap. Those are different implementations which are introduced in
>   Java 9. These implementations are internal and their constructors have
>   restricted access.

Конкретно в вашем случае это будет `java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN`

Answer (score 2):

метод `of` возвращает приватные реализации, в примере с `List.of(...)`, это не `ArrayList`, но это `list` основанный на массиве. Там же есть тонкости с вызовом например `of` с одним аргументом, тогда возвращается коллекция вообще не из массива, коллекция которая хранит в себе значение которое вы передали как приватное поле. Тоже самое с сетами. Вот реализация `of` для `List`

```
/**
 * Returns an unmodifiable list containing zero elements.
 *
 * See <a href="#unmodifiable">Unmodifiable Lists</a> for details.
 *
 * @param <E> the {@code List}'s element type
 * @return an empty {@code List}
 *
 * @since 9
 */
static <E> List<E> of() {
    return ImmutableCollections.List0.instance();
}
```

Как видите, возвращает она `List0`.

Такая же реализация и для `Set` и для `Map`, Set кстати возвращается не hash, а основанный на простом массиве

Вот метод который ищет эллемент в `Set` который возвращает `Set.of(...)`

```
    // returns index at which element is present; or if absent,
    // (-i - 1) where i is location where element should be inserted.
    // Callers are relying on this method to perform an implicit nullcheck
    // of pe
    private int probe(Object pe) {
        int idx = Math.floorMod(pe.hashCode() ^ SALT, elements.length);
        while (true) {
            E ee = elements[idx];
            if (ee == null) {
                return -idx - 1;
            } else if (pe.equals(ee)) {
                return idx;
            } else if (++idx == elements.length) {
                idx = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```